# Can not add row sum and column sum from array of objects using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some array of objects and I need to calculate the total value of each row and total values of each column and finally I will add new key to each object using Javascript. I am explaining my code below.

my input is like below.

```
let book_data= [ 
    { BranchName: 'Deeksha, Thanisandra, Bengaluru',
        Uniform: 2,
        Shoes: 1,
        Accessories: 1,
        Books: 5,
     },
      { BranchName: 'Deeksha, Thanisandra, Bengaluru',
        Uniform: 2,
        Shoes: 3,
        Accessories: 4,
        Books: 5,
      }
    ]
```

Here I need to add one more column `i.e-Grand total` to each row and this should contain the sum of all key value rather than `BranchName`. Similarly again I need to append one more new record  as last row and it should contant total value of each column. I am giving my sample output below.

[image]

I am explaining my code below.

```
for(let i=0; i<book_data.length; i++) {
        let grandRowTotal = 0;
        for(let key in book_data[i]) {
            if(key !== 'BranchName') {
                console.log('key', book_data[i][key]);
                grandRowTotal += parseInt(book_data[i][key]);
            }
        }
        book_data[i]['Grand Total'] = grandRowTotal;
        console.log('grandRowTotal', book_data[i],book_data);

    }
```

As per my code its not giving the expected result. I need here the sum of each row and column value as per my sample output above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created an extra array to keep track of the columns.

1. Basically what I do below is loop through the original array of `book_data`.
2. In each iteration i also loop through the `columns` data for each book.
3. This allows me to both modify the `GrandTotal` object and the `RowTotal` data

In your question you have two loops to loop through the book data. This is not necessary. Since its an array you can simply use the `forEach` method on an array.

Hope this helps :)

```js
    var book_data = [{
        BranchName: 'Deeksha, Thanisandra, Bengaluru',
        Uniform: 2,
        Shoes: 1,
        Accessories: 1,
        Books: 5,
      },
      {
        BranchName: 'Deeksha, Thanisandra, Bengaluru',
        Uniform: 2,
        Shoes: 3,
        Accessories: 4,
        Books: 5,
      }
    ];


    var ColumnTotals = {
      BranchName: 'Grand Total'
    };

    var columns = ['Uniform', 'Shoes', 'Accessories', 'Books'];

    book_data.forEach(b => {
      let rowTotal = 0;
      columns.forEach(i => {
        if (b[i] === undefined) {
          return;
        }

        ColumnTotals[i] = ColumnTotals[i] || 0;
        ColumnTotals[i] += b[i];
        rowTotal += b[i];
      })
      b.RowTotal = rowTotal;
    });

    // Calculate RowTotal for ColumnsTotals
    columns.forEach(i => {
      ColumnTotals.RowTotal = ColumnTotals.RowTotal || 0;
      ColumnTotals.RowTotal += ColumnTotals[i];
    })

    // Adding ColumnTotals to the Array
    book_data.push(ColumnTotals);

    console.log('BookData', book_data);
    console.table(book_data);
```

Comment: Ok, but the `ColumnTotals` should be the last row of the array.

Comment: Also other column headers rather than `BranchName` are dynamic.

Comment: I've added the grand total row to the original `book_data` hope this helps :)

Comment: The way that you are using the `map` function is wrong

Comment: agreed! changed to a simple forEach

Answer (score 0):

you need an object to keep the summary data, I change your code to this.
the fields of `summary` object will be added dynamically and you don't need to declare a variable for each field.

It has two advantages :
1. this is beneficial when each row has different fields.
2. when in the future a field like `car: 10` is added to the data you don't need to change your code.

```
let book_data = [
  {
    BranchName: 'Deeksha, Thanisandra, Bengaluru',
    Uniform: 2,
    Shoes: 1,
    Accessories: 1,
    Books: 5,
  },
  {
    BranchName: 'Deeksha, Thanisandra, Bengaluru',
    Uniform: 2,
    Shoes: 3,
    Accessories: 4,
    Books: 5,
  },
]

// the last row that show the summary
const summary = { BranchName: 'Grand Total', GrandTotal: 0 }
for (let i = 0; i < book_data.length; i++) {
  let grandRowTotal = 0
  for (let key in book_data[i]) {
    if (key !== 'BranchName') {
      const amount = parseInt(book_data[i][key])
      grandRowTotal += amount
      // calc the summary
      if (summary[key] === undefined) {
        summary[key] = 0
      }
      summary[key] += amount
      summary['GrandTotal'] += amount
    }
  }
  book_data[i]['GrandTotal'] = grandRowTotal
}
book_data.push(summary)

console.log(book_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `book_data[i]` is an object instead of an array, so you can't make use of `for`.

But, you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of object keys, then iterate like you are normally doing:

```
let key in Object.keys(book_data[i]) // instead of 'let key in book_data[i]' in your for
```

This should be enough to solve it